# PHP serialize array

Tags: php, serialization

I'm developing a wordpress theme which uses GBS.
In the database field values are stored like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:7:"Virtual";}
```

Which clearly uses serialize, However when I store a meta value and use php to serialize I get this:

```
s:24:"a:1:{i:0;s:7:"Virtual";}";
```

Is there any way to not get the string count of the entire array?
Here's the code I used:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'location', serialize(array('Virtual')) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's being double serialized, meaning update_post_meta serializes it already. Try it without your explicit call to serialize:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'location', array('Virtual'));
```

Comment: Yeah I was just being dopey I guess, works fine now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

update_post_meta seems to serialize whatever you send (a string of a serialized array in this time). Did you tried to change the thirs argument to just array('Virtual');??

Answer (score 0):

You can explode by `:` slice off the first two bits of the array and then implode back on ":" like so

```
$str = 's:24:"a:1:{i:0;s:7:"Virtual";}";';
$expected = '"a:1:{i:0;s:7:"Virtual";}";';
$bitsOfSerial = explode(":", $str);
$noStringLengthBits = array_slice($bitsOfSerial, 2);
$actual = implode(":", $noStringLengthBits);
assert($expected === $actual);
echo $actual;
```